# Replace Clone Attributes in a jQuery Clone?

Tags: jquery, clone

So I have a list I wan to clone and add new entries for:

```
<li class="splashEntry" data-counter="0">
    <select name="options[0][type]" class="textCtrl">...</select>
    <select name="options[0][sort]" class="textCtrl">...</select>
</li>
```

I am closing the field using `$('li.splashEntry').last().clone()` and getting the counter value using `.data('counter')`.

My question now would be, what would be the best way to update the data-counter field, and the select names in the subsequent created clone? Ideally, the cloned list item should have an incremented data-counter and select names. So the cloned field, which will appended to the end should be:

```
<li class="splashEntry" data-counter="1">
    <select name="options[1][type]" class="textCtrl">...</select>
    <select name="options[1][sort]" class="textCtrl">...</select>
</li>
```

Then since this new entry is appended to the end; if I click the button to create another clone, it should read the new data-counter as `1` (instead of 0 on the first row), and then create a new list item where all the entries say `2`.

What would be the best way to achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try something like

```
//cloned element
var $clone = $('li.splashEntry').last().clone(),
    //find the new counter value using old one
    counter = $clone.data('counter') + 1;
//update the data-counter attibute - used attribute instead of data because it gives a visual update on the dom
$clone.attr('data-counter', counter);
//update the name values
$clone.find('[name]').attr('name', function (_, name) {
    return name.replace(/\[\d+\]/, '[' + counter + ']')
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/7JQLP/)

Comment: New question... do you know how I would unselect the selected option from the clone?